# Divide negative number in VHDL by shifting

Tags: vhdl

I have a negative number(MSB=1). How can I divide the number by, say 2 , by shifting in VHDL.

Eg. shifting -6 should give me 2.

How can I generalize the division/shift
eg:-  -6  ->  -3
       6  ->   3

Comment: Have you tried just using /2? Any decent synthesis tool will implement it by shifting the value, and it shows your purpose in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For division by 2 of numbers (both negative and positive) in two's complement using `ieee.numeric_std.signed` it can be done using shift with:

```
res <= std_logic_vector(shift_right(signed(arg), 1));
```

The `shift_right` with signed argument will do arithmetic shifting, thus useful for division by 2 with a single bit shifted.

As MatthiasB points out in the comment, then division can also be used, with:

```
res <= std_logic_vector(signed(arg) / 2);
```

The difference in operation is:

- Shift (`shift_right`): Round down, thus -7 / 2 = -4
- Division (`/`): Rounds towards zero, thus -7 / 2 = -3

The difference in implementation:

- Shift (`shift_right`): Zero cost in size and speed, since done with wiring only
- Division (`/`): Some cost in size and speed, since logic operations are required for rounding