# Easiest Way to Shift Down A Signed Number

Tags: floating-point, vhdl, fpga, twos-complement

I am multiplying a 2s compliment floating point number and using it for some maths inside a DSP. I get the result and wish to shift it back down but I'm unsure of the easiest method.

For example:

```
constant b_const : integer := integer(real(1.0 / 3.0) / real((2.0**-10.0)));        
signal b : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0);

begin

b <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(b_const, b'length)) ; 

dsp: work.entity_dsp -- p = a * b
port map(
    clk => clk,
    a => a,
    b => b,
    p => p -- also signed
);

c <= p / 2**10; -- Isn't this very resource intensive ?
```

I had a look at the function "resize" but it just seems to either truncate or pad bits. I thought a golden rule of FPGAs was never to use "/" unless it realises a simple solution for what I'm trying to do?

Any advice?

Comment: The division is by a power of two, which is trivially implemented as a right shift (plus correction if operand negative) in signed integer or fixed-point arithmetic, and as an exponent subtraction in floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Maybe it is not clear what the correction for negative values should be when operating in signed integer/fixed-point arithmetic? Arithmetic right shift is division by a power of two, with *rounding of the result towards negative infinity*, while integer division by a power of two *truncates (rounds towards zero)* the result (in C, C++). So the necessary correction is: `if (x < 0) x = x + 2**n-1; r = x >> n;`, where `>>` denotes arithmetic right shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to truncate LSBs, you can use the shift_right function defined in numeric_std, followed by a resize.

```
c <= resize(shift_right(p, 10), c'length);
```

Alternatively, you can take a slice:

```
c <= p(c'length+10 downto 10);
```

Comment: But that would changed the value of the 2s compliment signed number

Comment: Yes, negative values are handled differently when dividing vs bitshifting. See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24145443/5900503  You can do as @njuffa suggested. Conditionally adding a constant for negative numbers before the right shift. Depending on the FPGA, this can be done using the post adder inside the DSP block without using extra LUTs.